# Why does apache redirect this PHP script back to itself when there is a sub-domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP script to serve pdf files if they have been marked as private and the user is logged in. Else it redirects the user to the log in screen. Which works okay.

However I have discovered if there is a sub-domain involved eg www.site.com the script or apache ends outputing the PHP source code to the browser.

I would like the script to work whether its on a sub-domain or not. And I am not sure if the issue is with the PHP script or the apache rewrite rules.

The server I want to put this on has this rewrite rule at the root dir, which seems to be causing the an issue. If I turn it off the script works until someone is on a sub-domain like www.

```
# root web dir /public_html/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.website.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I then have this rewrite rule in a subfolder to intercept requests to pdf files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) path/to/script/authenticate_user.php [L]
```

And this is the authenticate_user script

```
<?php

/**
 * Authenticate User before servicing a file.
 */

// Get WordPress location.
$parsed_uri = explode('wp-content', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'SCRIPT_FILENAME'));
// The requested file.
$request_uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI');

// Init WordPress.
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once $parsed_uri[0] . 'wp-blog-header.php';

// TODO add this option to settings.
$force_download = false;

// Check if the file is private.
global $wpdb;
$is_private = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT meta_value
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'is_private'
        AND meta_value = 'true'
        AND post_id = (
            SELECT id
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_name = %s
        )",
        sanitize_title(pathinfo($request_uri)['filename'])
    )
);

// If the file is NOT private OR the user is logged in.
// Serve the file.
if (!$is_private || is_user_logged_in()) {

    // Get the full path.
    $file = wp_normalize_path(ABSPATH . $request_uri);

    try {

        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            throw new Exception('File does not exist.');
        }

        if (!is_readable($file)) {
            throw new Exception('File is not readable.');
        }

        // Get file mime type.
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        // Send mime type AND replace status.
        // WordPress will send a 404 status as it does not recognise this script.
        header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $file), true, 200);
        finfo_close($finfo);

        if ($force_download) {
            // Use Content-Disposition: attachment to specify the filename.
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        }

        // No cache.
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');

        // Define file size.
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        // Send the file.
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
} else { // Else redirect to the login page.

    wp_safe_redirect(
        esc_url(
            wp_login_url($request_uri)
        )
    );

}

exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding another rewrite condition to point also in the php script.
something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
```

Comment: Nar that did nothing.